# Firebase security rules error "Property resource is undefined on object"

Tags: firebase-security

I have a function (and I've tested it without functions just to check if there isn't problem with reference or something):

```
function resourceIsValidSomething() {
  return request.resource.data.something is string ...;
}
```

and then:

```
allow create: if request.auth != null && resourceIsValidSomething();
```

and

```
allow update: if request.auth != null && resourceIsValidSomething();
```

But I get this error message when testing the **update rule**:

> Error: simulator.rules line [19], column [17]. Property resource is undefined on object.

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation), my rules should be correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Real example:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isGod() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 'god';
    }

    function allowedUser() {
        return request.resource.data.assignedTo.uid == request.auth.uid || isGod();
    }

    match /stores/{storeId} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null;

        match /imeis/{imeiId} {

        function resourceIsValidImei() {
            return request.resource.data.imei is string && 
            request.resource.data.imei.size() > 0 &&
            request.resource.data.type is string &&
            request.resource.data.type.size() > 0 &&
            request.resource.data.dateAdded is timestamp &&
            request.resource.data.createdBy.uid == request.auth.uid;
        }

        allow read: if request.auth != null;

        allow create: if request.auth != null &&
            isGod() && resourceIsValidImei();

        allow update: if request.auth != null && allowedUser();
      }
```

Comment: Does this happen in the emulator/CLI only? Or does this also happen when you deploy the rules, or test then in the console?

Comment: Also when I deploy and use in application. Creating data is ok, but when updating I get permissions problem

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't immediately see what's wrong. Can you edit the question to include the minimal, complete rules that reproduce the problem. I'm worried something may be getting lost in the snippets.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added the code

Comment: Thanks for that. I still don't see what's wrong, so I hope somebody else spots it.

Comment: Did you add simulation documents?

Comment: What do you mean @tobias please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> “Property resource is undefined on object”

You can't use a non-existent property in a Firebase rule expression.

For example, the following will raise a similar error.

```
read: if request.foobar == 'some value';
```

That's because `foobar` doesn't exist, and the rule will raise that it is `undefined`. The comparison with the `'some value'` on the right-hand side never happens, and the rest of the rule expressions are not evaluated.

Objects like `request` implement the `Map()` interface.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map

So you can rewrite your rule using the `Map.get()` method which doesn't raise an error and provides a default value for missing entries.

```
read: if request.get('foobar', null) == 'some value';
```

So now we're safely referring `foobar` in our rules.

> I have a function (and I've tested it without functions just to check if there isn't problem with reference or something):

Not all requests in the rules yield a `resource`. If the document does not exist the `resource` property on `request` is never set. So attempting to read it yields the above error. You can resolve this problem by checking for `null`.

```
function resourceIsValidSomething() {
  return request.get('resource', null) != null && request.resource.data.something;
}
```

You will probably still get a rule error like `false for "get" & L10`

That's because the `request.get('resource', null) != null` check is going to fail the rule. You can decide to *allow* access to documents that don't exist so that the query will complete.

The rule would look like this instead.

```
function resourceIsValidSomething() {
  return request.get('resource', null) == null || request.resource.data.something;
}
```

So allow access to missing resources or only resources with `data.something`.

It's up to you to decide which approach works best for your use-case.

Comment: omg, that makes it even more verbose. I have a custom claim that holds roles for each owner like this: request.auth.token.accessRules[ownerId].roles. Now in order to get roles I have to check token.get('accessRules', null) != null && token.accessRules.get('ownerId', null) !=null. I wish request.auth.token.accessRules[ownerId].roles could just safely fail returning null if any of the objects in the path doesn't exist. Ok, functions and wrappers to the rescue for now. +1 though, didn't know this syntax

Answer (score -3):

Try removing the `request.` from any instances of `request.resource`.  I.e. changing:

`return request.resource.data.assignedTo.uid == request.auth.uid || isGod();`

to just

`return resource.data.assignedTo.uid == request.auth.uid || isGod();`

It seems Google have updated their documentation in some areas but not others, but `resource` is no longer stored as a property of `request`

Comment: Just looking into this and I might be wrong. `request` and `request.resource` are traditionally very different things in Cloud Firestore security rules. One are the values before, another after a request was fulfilled. If this is still so, your advice may be misdirecting. This might explain the down vote (it wasn't me).

Comment: Straight from the documentation:
"When writing data, you may want to compare incoming data to existing data. In this case, if your ruleset allows the pending write, the request.resource variable contains the future state of the document. For update operations that only modify a subset of the document fields, the request.resource variable will contain the pending document state after the operation. You can check the field values in request.resource to prevent unwanted or inconsistent data updates"

Comment: I just ran into exactly this - copy-pasted from a rule that targets "create", but using it for one that targeted "read". `request.resource` is not available in the "read" context, so I got an error, wondering why everything was working fine with the rule I copied from.

Maybe you could update your response? It was exactly what I needed to do, but the downvotes had me ignore it initially :(