# Firestore Security Rule that allows writing only to user's own document?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to restrict documents in certain collections to only have write access to the user whose `uid` matches the document `id`. This does not work, however, as it produces an invalid permission error on the client.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        function isSignedIn() {
            return request.auth != null;
        }

        function isOwnDocument() {
            return request.auth.uid == request.resource.id;
        }

        match /userSettings/{doc} {
            allow write: if isOwnDocument();
            allow read: if isSignedIn();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the `doc` variable directly in the `isOwnDocument(docId)` function and then `return request.auth.uid == docId` ? It's mostly likely that `resource` is undefined on that object as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67138054/13130697)

Comment: @Dharmaraj that fixed it! Please post this is an answer, it may help other people.

Comment: Posted the same as answer. Sure, can check that out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `docId` variable directly in the `isOwnDocument()` function instead of reading from the `request.resource` object as shown below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        function isSignedIn() {
            return request.auth != null;
        }

        function isOwnDocument(docId) {
            return request.auth.uid == docId;
        }

        match /userSettings/{docId} {
            allow write: if isOwnDocument(docId);
            allow read: if isSignedIn();
        }
    }
}
```

The `resource` property might be `undefined` in explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67138054/13130697).

---

`request.auth.uid == resource.id` can be used to be but that'll throw an error if the document does not exist since your rule is works for `write` ops that includes `create` and `update` too). This rule will work only when used with `allow create:`. But best to pass the ID directly in the function parameters so it'll support both operations.

Comment: How do I use this with recursive wildcards? For example, if I have a collection `match /someCollection/{doc=**}` that has a few levels of subcollections in them with differing document names but the end documents (the ones that are being written to) have document IDs that match the user ID? Should I post this is a separate answer?

Comment: @kidcoder in that case `doc` will be _entire matching path segment_ as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) i.e. `/user1` in this case and not just `user1`.

Comment: Checkout the linked documentation once and see if your find your use case. If not, can you provide details of your use case with more details maybe in a new question?

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Then my only option would be to parse the string to extract the document ID? So basically forget it, right? Hah!

Comment: @kidcoder this [Firecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oip34d9oiEU) might be helpful for learning more about recursive wilcards. Again, if you don't seem to get a solution, please provide complete details of kind of rule are you looking for.